# WIndows Forms Project isn't working on another computer

Tags: c#

So, I have a project in WIndows Forms, in which I was getting data from Excel file and than displaying it in DGV. I have used Service-based Database to filter upcomming data from Excell file and OleDB to get data from Excell file. So everything is working perfectly and now I have just one Problem. When I have send this program to my friend he was getting following Error when he was trying to connect to DB.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR8Uw.png)

Why is he getting this error ? I think this is because that he hasn't installed sql server database on his computer

Comment: Does your friend's pc have all the .NET Runtime Software?

Comment: Does your friend have the Excel file, at the same location that you your app is looking for it? (P.S. please have the error as text in your questions, gives a faster overview than having to open a picture first)

Comment: Yes he has all the .NET Runtime Software. It isn't important to have excel file in the same location as I have on my PC

Comment: But he hasn't installed Library for OLDEDB. But in previous Project I have used OleDB but without SQL database and it worked perfectly.

Comment: From @pyro13g The excel file might have a specified path in your program and if your friend does not have the file in that path it wont be able to access it. Can you provide the section of code where it involves the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like he simply does not have rights to the database. Permission issue.

Comment: I think so too. How t check give him this permissions ?

Comment: Check what type of authentication you're using. What is your app using? It seems from your post your app somehow communicates with SQL Server, what does that connection string look like? Post more details.